# UnknownHost Exception in Android

Tags: android

My application was sending request to servlets frequently but since last day it starts giving **UnknownHostException Exception**.I don't know what is wrong with code which was working fine since 1 month.

I had added the permission to access internet in my manifest file .
My servlet is working fine with PC browser.

My code for calling servlet in Android is :

```
String url = "http://sampark.iiit.ac.in:8080/VTSServlets/CurrentTripInfo?mobilenum=##########&lat=10&long=10"
String response = getResponse(url);



public static String getResponse(final String url)
 {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    System.out.println("URL :: " + url);
    final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        final StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        final int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            final InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            builder.append("Not 200");
        }
    } catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

}
```

I have checked all requirements but dont know how it is giving UnknownHost Exception suddenly?I'm testing my application on android mobile.

Comment: **Your mobile have no internet connection or the Url you are calling is down**.

Answer (score 0):

Just **Close your emulator** and than run app means u need to restart your emulator this happen due to connectivity problem  if u are running in device than disconnect net connectivity like wifi disable and after enable it and check this problem id bcz of net connectivity problem and one more thing for webserivce app means getting data or image from net first check connectivity as shown below and than do your code

add this method in your activity or class

```
  protected boolean checkConnection(){ 
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    final boolean connected = networkInfo != null
            && networkInfo.isAvailable()
            && networkInfo.isConnected();

    if ( !connected) {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Failed to connect to internet. Check internet connection!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

add in menifest not only internet but this network state permission to check above condition

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and check condition as given below for connectivity

```
if(checkConnection()){

// Do here your all code as condition successfully satisfied
  }
```

Comment: @Khan : I have tried your suggestion .Thanks for help.But still it did not work then i have reset my android phone to factory settings and reinstall the fresh project and then it works fine.I still have not understand the issue.In one day it stopped working and after resetting all ,,it works fine.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: actully problem is of net connectivity be sure while coding that u have checked net connectivity there is no need to reset factory setting u have to reset your net connection for that

Comment: I had checked that the net connectivity.And at the time of exception the net was working fine.The application of news, weather update and mobile bowser of my phone were working.and accessing net but my application was saying the UnknownHostException.

Comment: in emulator is always show connected it works for device check in device after disonnecting net

Answer (score 0):

As checked your code is fine, check your mobile settings for connectivity. 
Try to uninstall and reinstall app (it may work) and also load url in browser (check that url returning json but before it returns this  ?  )

Comment: I had tried it many times but then after resetting my phone to factory settings it works fine.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: means you are not getting that exception anymore..??

Comment: @priyank 
When you r reset your phone factory settings all resources to their state before installing app so, in your app check how your connecting..
And i Suggest you to use HttPUrlConnection class which is almosst better than doing such type of connection it increase speed too
for more help check [link..](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
If this helps appreciate ...